# ImportError: No module name rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed. While creating a django project, I selected Python 3.5 as my python interpreter. And I also installed rest framework but I find this error while running my django project. Help

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named rest_framework
```

Comment: are you using virtualenv? if so, be sure that you have the virtualenv activated

Comment: You said you selected python3.5 but error is showing that it is running python2.7. Are you sure I've done it selection of interpreter correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry. I executed the command `python manage.py runserver` instead of `python3 manage.py runserver`

Working fine now.